# I am getting 403 forbidden error when using Import-DatabricksFolder powershell command in Azure Devops CI Pipeline

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-databricks, azure-pipelines-yaml

```
 Import-DatabricksFolder -BearerToken $bearerToken -Region $databricksWorkspaceInfo.location -LocalPath $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/${{parameters.notebooksPath}} -DatabricksPath 'Users/shankar@gmail.com/live' -Clean
```

The Response status code does not indicate success:

```bash
403 (Forbidden).
At /home/vsts/.local/share/powershell/Modules/azure.databricks.cicd.tools/2.2.5727/Public/Import-DatabricksFolder.ps1:61 char:17
+                 Throw $_.Exception
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], HttpResponseException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).
```

I have created the bearer token using OAuth Authentication from the link https://shorturl.at/jqBF7, and I have installed and imported `azure.databricks.cicd.tools`.
What am I missing in this to resolve error?

Comment: You have a permission issue with some of the Routes at the server.  The OAUTH2 authentication is working properly.   OAUTH2 is a two step authentication and step one is working properly where you are getting a token/cookie to access the server.  Step two is failing where you are trying to get access to a Route and failing because the credentials of the token do not have the correct permission.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Comment: @jdweng, I am using databricks api to copy local python files to remote databricks /live folder.

Comment: databricks is making an HTTP connection.  An HTTP connection has a client and server and is the same no matter what programming language or API you are using.  The databricks is the client and the client will fail if the server is no allowing the copy to occur.  Your server permissions are not allow the copy to occur.  The credentials of the client (user) is being blocked by the server.  The link I provided shows examples of the permissions in the server.

Answer (score 0):

> What am i missing in this to resolve error?

```
# Make sure the bearer token and paths are correctly set
Import-DatabricksFolder -BearerToken $bearerToken `
                        -Region $databricksWorkspaceInfo.location `
                        -LocalPath $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/${{parameters.notebooksPath}} `
                        -DatabricksPath 'Users/shankar@gmail.com/live' `
                        -Clean
```

- Make sure the [bearer token you are using has the necessary permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts#access-tokens) to access the Databricks workspace and perform operations like importing folders.
- Verify the path `'Users/shankar@gmail.com/live'`. It should be a valid path in your Databricks workspace where you have access.
- If Databricks workspace has network policies, make sure your Azure DevOps agent's IP is whitelisted.

---

> I am sure I am having access for `Users/shankar@gmail.com/live`: this path which is inside workspaces in databricks.
>
> ```
> curl -X GET --header "Authorization: Bearer $OAUTH_TOKEN" \
> 'https://adb-223749328.6.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/clusters/list'" this is working.
> ```
>
> If I have to whitelist agent's IP, how can I do that?

To whitelist the Azure DevOps Agent's IP in Databricks, you would need first to identify the Agent's IP address.
If you are using a self-hosted agent, you should already know its IP address.
If you are using a Microsoft-hosted agent, its IP address can change. You can add a task in your pipeline to print the IP address using a command like `curl ifconfig.me` or `curl ipinfo.io/ip`.

Then add the IP Address to Databricks Network Policy: in your Databricks workspace, go to the admin console under 'Settings', 'Network' tab. Under 'Network Security', find the IP Access List feature. Add a new entry with the IP address of your Azure DevOps agent.

Make sure your pipeline is configured to use the same region as your Databricks workspace.
After adding the IP address to the whitelist, re-run the pipeline to see if the issue is resolved.

Warning: If using Microsoft-hosted agents, their IP addresses can change. You might have to use a range of IP addresses or regularly update the whitelist.

See also "[Deploy Azure Databricks in your Azure virtual network (VNet injection)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/network/classic/vnet-inject#network-security-group-rules-for-workspaces-created-after-january-13-2020)".
For instance, review NSG (Network Security Group) rules associated with the subnets used by your Databricks workspace, to make sure there are no rules inadvertently blocking the specific traffic required by the `Import-DatabricksFolder` command.

---

The fact that whitelisting all IP addresses (0.0.0.0) did not resolve the `403 Forbidden` error suggests that the issue is not likely related to network security configurations, such as IP whitelisting or network security group (NSG) rules. Instead, it points towards other potential causes, specifically related to authentication and authorization.

As noted by [jdweng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5015238/jdweng) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77853461/i-am-getting-403-forbidden-error-when-using-import-databricksfolder-powershell-c/77853491#comment137252920_77853461), this could be a permissions problem related to the routes on the server.
The successful generation and retrieval of the OAuth2 token suggest that the authentication process (the first step of OAuth2) is working correctly. However, the `403 Forbidden` error during the second step, where you are trying to access a specific route (API endpoint), indicates a lack of the necessary permissions for that action.

The ["Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0) documentation page, describes the principles of routing and permissions.

Make sure the service principal used to generate the OAuth2 token has permissions to access the specific Databricks API endpoint you are trying to reach. Permissions might need to be configured both at the account level and within the specific Databricks workspace.
Double-check the API endpoint you are trying to access. Make sure it is valid and accessible with your service principal's permissions.
Verify that the OAuth token is generated with the correct scope. If your token is scoped to a different level (e.g., account-level vs. workspace-level), it might not authorize access to certain endpoints.

Comment: I am sure i am having access for Users/shankar@gmail.com/live this path which is inside workspaces in databricks. "curl -X GET --header "Authorization: Bearer $OAUTH_TOKEN" \
'https://adb-223749328.6.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/clusters/list' " this is working. If I have to whitelist agent's IP how can i do that

Comment: I have tried giving all IP address to whitelist (0.0.0.0), however i still facing same error.

Comment: @uma_8331 OK. I have edited the answer, with some suggestions and checks around permission.